# Gapless grid layout that doesn't squash tiles

Tags: layout, web, grid

I'm looking for a gapless grid layout plugin for my web app. There are a lot out there but none of them do quite what I need. Most of them squash tiles to fit gaps, which hides content. I'd much rather adjacent tiles stretched to fill the gap, which preserves the functionality of the tiles content, i.e. nothing is hidden.

Basic requirements are:

- Drag & droppable
- Responsive (althought I can fake this with an onResize listener)
- Gapless, i.e. there are no gaps in the grid, tiles stretch to fill width and gaps
- Works with differently sized tiles, i.e. not uniform width like pintrest
- Works with a few large tiles. Most plugins require many small tiles to fill gaps. My app will have between 4-8 large and small tiles.
- Tiles may stretch, but not shrink. Shruken tiles make their contents unusuably small.

I have considered:

- Gridster, not gapless
- Freewall, squishes tiles to fit in gaps, only works well with many
  small tiles
- Gridly, not gapless without many small tiles
- Masonry, not drag and drop
- Wookmark, not draggable
- Nested, not gapless without many small tiles
- Pinbox, uniform width
- Shapeshift, not gapless

Are there any other plugins that might meet the requirements? Is there any way to coerce any of the above into meeting them?